# What languages aren't considered OOP languages

Tags: oop, object, language-agnostic

Every programming/scripting language that I have heard of is an Object Oriented Programming (O.O.P) language. What are some examples of languages that aren't considered an O.O.P language.

Comment: What do you know about the definition of an OOP language? Which languages don't satisfy that definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OOP is a paradigm, not language. Some languages like Javascript or PHP can use OOP, but don't need to (they are multiparadigmatic).

Some languages like C# or Java have to use objects, but that doesn't mean the programs need to be Object-Oriented. In that case it is considered bad design, though. There are even [antipatterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Object-oriented_programming) that describe screwed OOP, although C# supports coding sugar like lambdas or linq that is not OOP.

Some people try to emulate their favorite paradigm in languages that don't support it well. For example, jQuery tries to use functional (or monadic) paradigm and some say it is not a good idea (although the library is very popular).

I recommend [this article](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/paradigms_themes-paradigm-overview-section.html) to get grasp of most popular paradigms and their difference to OOP.

Answer (score 3):

Assembly, C, BASIC, Fortran, Forth, Pascal, Brainf**k, Malbolge, and dozens upon dozens more.

Comment: In that list, at least Basic and Pascal are OO

Comment: @slebetman: Some variants support OOP. The base languages themselves do not.